# I'm in trouble with creating first helloworld app using arcgis android

Tags: android, arcgis-android, arcgis-runtime-sdk-java

I made my first application using arcgis android sdk but when ı'm launching helloworld app emulator didn't launch the map.
Read all questions and documents..Still didnt find any solution to solve this problem. Here is my screenshots;

Eclipse View  -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/FzvPK.jpg

Emulator View -  https://i.stack.imgur.com/an2zi.jpg

Comment: Looks like Eclipse has issues connecting to the emulator. Have you been able to run any other application from eclipse within the emulator? Also note that only some emulators are supported. See this: http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/05/02/arcgis-runtime-sdk-for-android-v1-1-supports-android-emulator/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reply on my answer, Esri's maps are not working properly on emulator. Only x86 haxm google api emulators run the Esri's map. But i recommend use real device for testing app.